# IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred when traying create webservice for given WSDL:Proxy Authorization Required

Tags: java, web-services

1. I created a Dynamic web project
2. Imported the WSDL file into Webcontent of the project
3. I go to file-> New-> Webservice-> Webservice
4. I adjusted all the settings accordingly, but after finsihing its throwing the follwing 
   error;

   ```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The char '0x0' after 'return code:  407
   <HEAD><TITLE>Proxy Authorization Required</TITLE></HEAD>
   <BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Proxy Authorization Required</H1><HR>
   <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
   Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy</B></FONT>
   <HR>
   <!-- default "Proxy Authorization Required" response (407) -->
   </BODY>
   ' is not a valid XML character.
   at org.apache.axis.components.encoding.AbstractXMLEncode(AbstractXMLEncoder.java:110)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of improper setup of Axis2.

Steps:

1. Download Axis2 : Link--> http://ws.apache.org/axis2/download.cgi
2. Point the Axis2 runtime dir in eclipse :  Menu--> Windows--> Preference -->  Web Services--> Axis2 Preferences

Follow this link for more details: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for you. I was also facing the same problem, but this solution worked for me. Just try.

Upto WSDL creation, u have done rite?

Just right click on the Java file which you have created for WS.

Select WEb Services --> Create Web Service

Now select the Web Service type as " Bottom Up" approach.

Select the Client type bar selection upto "Test Client" (full).

Now give Finish and check.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this problem can occurs because temp files

- Close Eclipse
- Delete org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.core.prefs file
- Delete .cxftmp folder
- Restart eclipse

and check it is working or not