# IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred while creating web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I'm trying to create a web service, as I am new to web service development I followed the following [post](http://javapapers.com/web-service/java-web-service-using-eclipse/).
I am using  Ecplise Helios,Windows 7 32 bit,Tomcat v6.0

There are three steps:
1.Create Dynamic Web project.
2. Create Web Service Provider Java Class.
3.Create a Web Service.

At point 3.create a Web service I am getting two error:

1.Several ports (8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

This error has been resolved using one of the community post.

2.IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.
     The char '0x0' after 'return code:  400
    Cycle Detected

## Cycle Detected

---

**Description: Your request is prohibited because it would cause a cycle.**

---

' is not a valid XML character.

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The char '0x0' after 'return code:  400
  <HEAD><TITLE>Cycle Detected</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Cycle Detected</H1><HR>
  <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
  Description: Your request is prohibited because it would cause a cycle.</B></FONT>
```

This error is some what similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100402/iwab0014e-unexpected-exception-occurred-when-traying-create-webservice-for-given) but the error code returned is different in my case it is **"400"**

Any tips on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of improper setup of Axis2.

Steps:

1. Download Axis2 : Link--> http://ws.apache.org/axis2/download.cgi
2. Point the Axis2 runtime dir in eclipse :  Menu--> Windows--> Preference -->  Web Services--> Axis2 Preferences

Follow this link for more details: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html